# Xcode iPad or iPhone Build Size Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Had a question and if anyone has found similar issues. It seems my file size keeps growing. I have had to import existing files and then delete them from the project. It seems that it keeps those files somewhere. From being 40mb and importing a few .WAV files at 30mb each it goes up to 100mb. After I deleted them it seems it doesn't change the file size.

This was a similar issue in Flash IDE - Saving as a new project name would solve this. I'm unsure if it does in Xcode.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Thanks,
-Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you've done a fully clean build since removing the resources? Do a Build->Clean for the target(s) you care about, delete the app binary off the simulator and device for full certainty, and rebuild. If there really isn't a reference to the resource in the project any more, this should ensure it goes away from the resulting bundle.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I didn't realize about cleaning it under Build -> 

My build went from 166mb to 33mb, so much better. And it also solved the issue from deleting an audio file named song.mp3 and then importing the same name again and it thinking it was the old track.

Cheers for the answer.

Comment: No worries-- this bit me just the other day. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Which files specifically are causing the problem? Try using the du command to work out where the space is going.